# Compile-time assertions in C++?

Tags: c++

I recently came upon the need to have compile-time assertions in C++ to check that the sizes of two types were equal.

I found the following macro on the web (stated to have come from the Linux kernel):

```
#define X_ASSERT(condition) ((void)sizeof(char[1 - 2*!!(condition)]))
```

which I used like so:

```
X_ASSERT(sizeof(Botan::byte) != sizeof(char));
```

This gets me curious - although this *works*, is there a cleaner way to do so? (obviously there's more than one way, as it is) Are there advantages or disadvantages to certain methods?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers everyone, very interesting. I'm glad to see C++0x is getting `static_assert`, I don't remember having read about that before. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Boost StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html). The internals aren't exactly clean (or weren't the last time I looked) but at least it's much more recognizable, so most people know what it means. It also goes to some pains to produce more meaningful error messages if memory serves.

Comment: I actually prefer [`BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/assert-msg.html).

Answer (score 10):

In C++0x, there is a new language feature, `static_assert`, which provides a standard way to generate compile-time assertions.  For example,

```
static_assert(sizeof(Botan::byte) != 1, "byte type has wrong size");
```

Visual C++ 2010 supports `static_assert`, as do g++ 4.3 (and greater) and Intel C++ 11.0.

Answer (score 1):

Some other interesting options are here:  http://www.jaggersoft.com/pubs/CVu11_3.html

Neat reading as the author walks the C (not C++) spec looking for syntax that can be leveraged as compile-time assertions.

Answer (score 1):

To do it **right** you need a C++0x friendly compiler, see James McNellis' and Jerry Coffins answers.

You can't do much with the 1998 or 2003 C++ standards. Take a look at these links for examples:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(computing)#Static_assertions
http://ksvanhorn.com/Articles/ctassert.html

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent `#error` preprocessor directive (see [here](http://www.netrino.com/node/138) for a good essay about it), but I believe it needs to be within a `#if` as opposed to being used in a "free-standing" as in your example use.

Comment: `#error` has the disadvantage that it is a preprocessing directive and is evaluated before the source is parsed, and you can't use things like `sizeof` or non-macro constants in the controlling `#if` directive.